# Multi-Layered PictureBox Component

Tags: c#, .net, graphics, picturebox

Is there any multi-layered picturebox control? I don't look for a solution like loop every layer with Graphics.DrawImage than draw layered image to picturebox. This approach is very inefficient. I'm working on very big images. Actually, I'm a directX programmer, and there is clipping when you draw with directX. The image is being rendered for only the viewport, other out of the view parts of the image aren't rendered. I can implement this, but I don't want to struggle with this now, I'm looking for a true component that does that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wrote a layered control that derives from `Control`, and it has pan/zoom and selection options like photoshop. I'll release this control here with a link to download soon.
Regards.